# cloneNode(true) is not copying child elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following:

```
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('projectListDiv');
var projectList = getProjects();
/* getProjects() generates a <select> element with multiple <option>s */
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
    divs[i].innerHTML = "";
    var listCopy = projectList.cloneNode(true);
    divs[i].appendChild(listCopy);
}
```

getProjects() returns the following:

```
<select>
    <option value="test">test</option>
    <option value="Project Test">Stalker Test</option>
</select>
```

Which should theoretically append a `<select>` element to each div with the class `projectListDiv`. It does append a `<select>` element but the element has no `<options` despite the fact that `projectList` clearly has options. I have logged everything to console to check and for some reason when I `cloneNode(true)` I lose all of `projectList`'s children. Thoughts?

Comment: You forgot to post the most important part, what does `getProjects()` return

Comment: @adeneo ...Did you see the /* comment */?

Comment: I did, but that tells us nothing, cloneNode should work, if it doesn't something is wrong whith the returned content, and we don't know what that is ?

Comment: @adeneo I added the console.log of projectList

Comment: But that's just HTML, are you returning *nodes* or just strings? You can't clone a string.

Comment: @adeneo it's nodes. When I log projectList it links me to an HTML inspector where I can expand the select element to see it's option children

Comment: Well, I don't know, it should work, and unless you post the `getProjects` function noone can really tell you what the problem is, but you can look at the answer below (that should have been a comment) and see that it works just fine with actual nodes.

Comment: Please replace my getProjects with your getProjects() function inside the jsfiddle.

Comment: @adeneo I just used the getProjects() below and it works, but the selects created by my getProjects along with the getProjects below are functionally identical. Like I can append projectList by itself and it works with no problem. But copies of it are empty.

Comment: @progysm see the above response

Comment: I don't see any functionnal code above for getProjects. @NickChapman

Comment: As in `divs[i].appendChild(projectList)` will add the appropriate thing but of course you can't append the same node to multiple places in the DOM.

Comment: Even if you can append it, it's probably not nodes, you need actual nodes to use cloneNode, hence the name.

Comment: @progysm I can't really give you a working version of getProjects because it's doing an ajax call to a MySQL server which generates a list of projects which are then returned to the page. The array of projects is then looped through and converted into a select element using `createElement('option')` to create each option which is then `.appendChild()`-ed into the `<select>` element created at the beginning of the function. This is all then returned. So I guess the question is can you not return a node?

Comment: @adeneo, can you not return a node?

Comment: Unless you are doing a sync call, you can't return anything with a async (ajax) function. You need to send a callback to continue with the answer or use a promise.

Comment: Yes you can, but returning from an ajax call is trickier, are you sure the problem is async behaviour

Comment: I call that "sjax" when you use xmlhttprequest in sync mode :-p

Comment: @adeneo, if the problem was async behavior then wouldn't `console.log`-ing immediately after `projectList = getProjects()` result in a NULL or something like that?

Comment: It should, good point. Try `console.log(typeof projectList)` and see what that gets you.

Comment: if getProjects() is { var s = document.createElement('select'); /* do ajax call (async) */  return s; }  then the code will work, but the options will be appended much later, after the cloning.

Comment: @adeneo did that earlier to make sure it wasn't a string and I got object. This is weird as hell right? Like everything says this should work.

Comment: @adeneo hmmmm. Even though it logs typeof as an object, it logs the tagname as a string.

Comment: @adeneo WTF?! It says that projectList is a string yet if I try to use string properties on it I am told that it is not a string. I have no idea what the hell is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made an example in http://jsfiddle.net/NSYRH/  with a custom getProjects() that return a select with options:

```
function getProjects() {
    var s = document.createElement('select');
    s.appendChild(new Option('a','avalue'));
    s.appendChild(new Option('b','bvalue'));
    s.appendChild(new Option('c','cvalue')); 
    return s;
}
```

I don't see any problem with this code.

Comment: Alright I'm going to take this as the answer, though I will ask that you combine this answer with the other one. Nothing worked and I ultimately had to run a call to getProjects twice which is horribly inefficient but it works and this is a small scale program so I'm not too worried about it.

Comment: the only code to change in the second answer is how you receive your data (xml, string, json string) and create the option with this data.

Answer (score 0):

Async mode, with callback:

```
getProjects(function(projectList) {
   var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('projectListDiv');
   /* getProjects() generates a <select> element with multiple <option>s */
   for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++){
       divs[i].innerHTML = "";
       var listCopy = projectList.cloneNode(true);
       divs[i].appendChild(listCopy);
   }
})

function getProjects(successCallback) {
  var s = document.createElement('select');
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
  xhr.open('GET', '/something');
  xhr.onload = function() {
     /** use xhr.responseText here to add option to node s */
     /* then call the successCalback) */
     successCallback(s);
  }
  xhr.send();
}
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NSYRH/1/  here is a jsfiddle that receive JSON data, append each option to the select, and then fill each div.